# Spring STS can't find META-INF/spring.schemas

Tags: eclipse, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Trying to set up a new project, and running into a weird issue.  I made a new app context file named backend-context.xml, I've added spring-context as a dependency, and am trying to add namespaces through the bean config file, but it's showing as 1 error, with no explaination.

If I browse into problem explorer, it states the following error:

'Unable to load schema mappings from location [META-INF/spring.schemas]'

If I browse through the Maven Dependencies I can see this file located under the spring-beans jar.

If anyone has ideas on how to fix this, that'd be awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ended up being caused by a local maven jar being corrupt.  Found this out by uploading the code to github and trying on a different computer which worked like a charm.  So, cleaned out my local repository from all spring jars and redownloaded.